# Problema com Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Estou tentando aprender sobre o hibernate junto a um tutorial fazendo um aplicativo para uma petshop e estou com os seguintes problemas:

```
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.banho
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [idservico]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_8bc8p6qj2ek64yrb76s976rjf]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.cachorro
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [idpet]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_m1qtvr24qy5xjxnemmd9oic16]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.cliente
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [senha, tipo, nome, idcliente, email]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.consulta
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [idservico]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_6qm9x1xxks3unkgaob3i99d03]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.docreceita
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [iddocreceita, tipo, numero, idcliente]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_j4avp8ra42thcbkyewl6b1k2h]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_j4avp8ra42thcbkyewl6b1k2h, primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.endereco
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [uf, cidade, numero, bairro, lograd, idendereco, complement, idcliente, cep]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_be5ys2q5h8kp2jbo3na5i375h]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_be5ys2q5h8kp2jbo3na5i375h, primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.gato
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [idpet]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_griths664hfg8ouo2sno5nh2f]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.pf
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [idcliente]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_qxjleuo0xbnb1tle975pj3j8e]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.pj
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [idcliente]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_8w9emf3u9u8xwfs06kg7t3cn1]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init> 
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.telefone
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [codarea, numero, idtelefone, idcliente]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init> 
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_8ebk7ukc8bu6le5maqc22j7fe]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_8ebk7ukc8bu6le5maqc22j7fe, primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.tosa
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init> 
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [idservico]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_i1bl4hfp3l6vxfaof4an77ixv]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.vacina
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [idservico]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_8hjpu55jfw6hofemns2b2q8v0]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.pet
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [obs, tipo, idpet, raca, nome, sexo, datanascimento, idcliente, descricao]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_p0g8vb4xgsxek1s5jao9u4prw]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_p0g8vb4xgsxek1s5jao9u4prw, primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: petshop1.servico
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [data_dia, obs, tipo, idpet, valor, nome, idservico, descricao]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_lny299dytlemb03botpbk0f8b]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_lny299dytlemb03botpbk0f8b, primary]
dez 16, 2015 8:34:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Hibernate: select cliente0_.idCliente as idClient2_2_, cliente0_.email as email3_2_, cliente0_.nome as nome4_2_, cliente0_.senha as senha5_2_, cliente0_.tipo as tipo1_2_ from Cliente cliente0_ left outer join PF cliente0_1_ on cliente0_.idCliente=cliente0_1_.idCliente left outer join PJ cliente0_2_ on cliente0_.idCliente=cliente0_2_.idCliente where cliente0_.email=? and cliente0_.senha=?
Erro na autenticação
Hibernate: select docreceita0_.idDocReceita as idDocRec2_4_, docreceita0_.idCliente as idClient4_4_, docreceita0_.numero as numero3_4_, docreceita0_.tipo as tipo1_4_ from DocReceita docreceita0_ where docreceita0_.numero=?
Hibernate: insert into Cliente (email, nome, senha, tipo) values (?, ?, ?, '1')
dez 16, 2015 8:34:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelperlogExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
dez 16, 2015 8:34:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelperlogExceptions
ERROR: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: couldnotinsert[br.com.diego.controle.PF]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardS    QLExceptionConverter.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java    :126)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturnin    gDelegate.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPers    ister.java:3032)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPers    ister.java:3556)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityI    nsertAction.java:97)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:480)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.j    ava:191)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:175)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:210)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractS    aveEventListener.java:324)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(Ab    stractSaveEventListener.java:288)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveE    ventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(Abstr    actSaveEventListener.java:125)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedO    rRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequest    edId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(    DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(Defaul    tSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(Def    aultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:711)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:703)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:698)
at br.com.diego.modelo.ClienteMTD.salvar(ClienteMTD.java:26)
at br.com.diego.controle.Cliente.salvar(Cliente.java:89)
at br.com.diego.modelo.TestandoHibernate.persistindo(TestandoHibernate.java:112)
at br.com.diego.modelo.TestandoHibernate.main(TestandoHibernate.java:32)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3813)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3795)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3840)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInt(PreparedStatement.java:3784)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDesc    riptor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicTy    pe.java:282)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicTy    pe.java:277)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSin    gleColumnStandardBasicType.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityP    ersister.java:2843)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityP    ersister.java:2818)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$4.bindValues(AbstractEnti    tyPersister.java:3025)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturnin    gDelegate.java:57)
... 23 more
```

Classe Cliente.java :

```
package br.com.diego.controle;

import br.com.diego.modelo.ClienteMTD;
import java.io.Serializable; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import org.hibernate.annotations.*;


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "tipo")
public abstract class Cliente implements Autenticavel, Serializable {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int idCliente;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 2)
private int tipo;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 250)
private String nome;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 250)
private String email;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 250)
private String senha;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Telefone> telefone;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Endereco> endereco;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Pet> pet;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "cliente", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
private DocReceita docReceita;

public static int PF = 1;
public static int PJ = 2;


public Cliente() {
}

public Cliente(int idCliente, int tipo, String nome, Collection<Telefone>      telefone, Collection<Endereco> endereco, Collection<Pet> pet, String email,     String senha, DocReceita docReceita) {

    this.idCliente = idCliente;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.nome = nome;       
    this.telefone = telefone;
    this.endereco = endereco;
    this.pet = pet;
    this.email = email;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.docReceita = docReceita;

}

public Autenticavel autenticar(String usuario, String senha){
    return ClienteMTD.autenticar(usuario, senha);
    }

public boolean existe(String email){
    return ClienteMTD.existe(email);
    }

public boolean existe(DocReceita documento){
    return ClienteMTD.existe(documento);    
    }

static public boolean salvar(Cliente p){
    return ClienteMTD.salvar(p);
    }   

static public ArrayList<Cliente>consultar(){
    return ClienteMTD.consultar();
    }

static public Cliente consultar(int idCliente){
    return ClienteMTD.consultar(idCliente);
    }

static public Collection<Cliente> consultar(String nome){
    return ClienteMTD.consultar(nome);
    }

static public boolean alterar(Cliente p){
    return ClienteMTD.alterar(p);
    }

static public boolean excluir(Cliente p){
    return ClienteMTD.excluir(p);
    }

/**
 * @return the idCliente
 */
public int getIdCliente() {
    return idCliente;
}

/**
 * @param idCliente the idCliente to set
 */
public void setIdCliente(int idCliente) {
    this.idCliente = idCliente;
}

/**
 * @return the tipo
 */
public int getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

/**
 * @param tipo the tipo to set
 */
public void setTipo(int tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

/**
 * @return the nome
 */
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

/**
 * @param nome the nome to set
 */
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

/**
 * @return the telefone
 */
public Collection<Telefone> getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

/**
 * @param telefone the telefone to set
 */
public void setTelefone(Collection<Telefone> telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

/**
 * @return the endereco
 */
public Collection<Endereco> getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

/**
 * @param endereco the endereco to set
 */
public void setEndereco(Collection<Endereco> endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

/**
 * @return the pet
 */
public Collection<Pet> getPet() {
    return pet;
}

/**
 * @param pet the pet to set
 */
public void setPet(Collection<Pet> pet) {
    this.pet = pet;
}

/**
 * @return the email
 */
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

/**
 * @param email the email to set
 */
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

/**
 * @return the senha
 */
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

/**
 * @param senha the senha to set
 */
public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

/**
 * @return the docReceita
 */
public DocReceita getDocReceita() {
    return docReceita;
}

/**
 * @param docReceita the docReceita to set
 */
public void setDocReceita(DocReceita docReceita) {
    this.docReceita = docReceita;
}
}
```

ClienteMTD.java

```
package br.com.diego.modelo;

import br.com.diego.controle.Autenticavel;
import br.com.diego.controle.DocReceita;
import br.com.diego.controle.Cliente;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

/**
*
* @author diego
*/
public class ClienteMTD {


public static boolean salvar(Cliente p) {
    Session session;
    session = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(p);
        tx.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public static Cliente consultar(int idCliente) {
    Session session;
    session = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Cliente p = null;
    try {
        Query q;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        q = session.createQuery("FROM Cliente as p where p.idCliente=:id");
        q.setParameter("id", idCliente);
        List resultados = q.list();
        if (resultados.size() > 0) {
            p = (Cliente) resultados.get(0);
        }
        return p;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return p;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Cliente> consultar() {
    Session session;
    session = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
    Transaction tx = null;
    ArrayList<Cliente> p = null;
    try {
        Query q;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        q = session.createQuery("FROM Cliente as p");
        p = (ArrayList<Cliente>) q.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return p;
}

public static Collection<Cliente> consultar(String nome) {
    Session session;
    session = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Collection<Cliente> p = null;
    try {
        Query q;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        q = session.createQuery("FROM Cliente as p where p.nome=:nome");
        q.setParameter("nome", nome);
        p = q.list();
        return p;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return p;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public static boolean alterar(Cliente p) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.merge(p);
        tx.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public static boolean excluir(Cliente p) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(p);
        tx.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public static Autenticavel autenticar(String usuario, String senha) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Cliente p = null;
    try {
        Query q;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        q = session.createQuery("FROM Cliente as p where p.email=:usuario and p.senha=:senha");
        q.setParameter("usuario", usuario);
        q.setParameter("senha", senha);
        List resultados = q.list();
        if (resultados.size() > 0) {
            p = (Cliente) resultados.get(0);
        }
        return p;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return p;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public static boolean existe(String usuario) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
    Transaction tx = null;
     try {
        Query q;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        q = session.createQuery("FROM Cliente as p where p.email=:usuario");
        q.setParameter("usuario", usuario);
        List resultados = q.list();
        if (resultados.size() > 0) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao consultar existência de usuário");
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public static boolean existe(DocReceita documento) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
    Transaction tx = null;
     try {
        Query q;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        q = session.createQuery("FROM DocReceita as d where d.numero=:documento");
        q.setParameter("documento", documento.getNumero());
        List resultados = q.list();
        if (resultados.size() > 0) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao consultar existência de usuário com o documento solicitado");
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
}
```

Autenticavel.java :

```
package br.com.diego.controle;

public interface Autenticavel {

public Autenticavel autenticar(String usuario, String senha);

public boolean existe(String usuario);
}
```

TestandoHibernate.java :

```
package br.com.diego.modelo;

import br.com.diego.controle.Autenticavel;
import br.com.diego.controle.CPF;
import br.com.diego.controle.Cachorro;
import br.com.diego.controle.Consulta;
import br.com.diego.controle.DocReceita;
import br.com.diego.controle.Endereco;
import br.com.diego.controle.PF;
import br.com.diego.controle.Pet;
import br.com.diego.controle.Servico;
import br.com.diego.controle.Telefone;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;

public class TestandoHibernate {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    GerarTabelas();

    if (autenticar("diegopvj@gmail.com", "root") != null) {
        System.out.println("Usuário autenticado");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Erro na autenticação");
    }
    try {
        persistindo();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

 public static Autenticavel autenticar(String usuario, String senha) {
    return new PF().autenticar(usuario, senha);
}

 private static void GerarTabelas() {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SchemaExport sx = new SchemaExport(cfg);
    sx.create(true, true);

}

private static void excluindo() {
}

 private static void persistindo() throws Exception {
    PF pf = new PF();
    pf.setNome("Diego");
    pf.setEmail("diegopvj@gmail.com");
    pf.setSenha("root");

    DocReceita CPF = new CPF(" 123. 359. 769-67 ");
    pf.setDocReceita(CPF);
    CPF.setCliente(pf);

    if (pf.existe(CPF) == true) {
        throw new RuntimeException("<br><center><font face='verdana' color='red'   size='2'><br />já existe usuário cadastrado com o CPF ou CNPJ informado</font></center><br>");
    }

    Endereco end = new Endereco();
    end.setBairro("Centro");
    end.setCep("28610180");
    end.setCidade("Nova Friburgo");
    end.setLograd("Pca Presidente Getulio Vargas");
    end.setNumero("203");
    end.setUf("RJ");
    end.setCliente(pf);

    Collection<Endereco> e = new ArrayList<Endereco>();
    e.add(end);
    pf.setEndereco(e);

    Telefone t = new Telefone();
    t.setCodArea(21);
    t.setNumero("983337760");
    t.setCliente(pf);

    Collection<Telefone> tel = new ArrayList<Telefone>();
    tel.add(t);
    pf.setTelefone(tel);

    Pet a = new Cachorro();
    Date d = new Date(2010, 4, 26);
    a.setDataNascimento(d);
    a.setNome("Rex");
    a.setRaca("Bulldog");
    a.setSexo('M');
    a.setObs("Peida muito!");
    a.setCliente(pf);

    Servico s = new Consulta();
    s.setData(new Date());
    s.setDescricao("Problema de peso");
    s.setValor(20);
    s.setPet(a);

    Collection<Servico> serv = new ArrayList<Servico>();
    serv.add(s);
    a.setServico(serv);

    Collection<Pet> peti = new ArrayList<Pet>();
    peti.add(a);
    pf.setPet(peti);

    PF.salvar(pf);
}    
}
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar?
Obrigado desde ja!

Comment: Quais são os problemas que esta tendo? Vc poderia isola-los, assim ficar melhor para solucionar?

Comment: Na DiscriminatorColumn foi setado tipo, mas foi explicito para ser uma String? Da uma olhada o tipo de propriedade que foi criado no banco de dados para o atributo tipo.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho meu mair problema é este: `Hibernate: insert into Cliente (email, nome, senha, tipo) values (?, ?, ?, '1')
dez 16, 2015 8:34:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelperlogExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
dez 16, 2015 8:34:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelperlogExceptions
ERROR: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).`

Comment: @DouglasGaldino está desse jeito https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8lZMvD1tbzRSkZuWVlsOEl5cE0

Comment: Como está o método de salvar da classe `PFMTD`?

Comment: @GustavoCinque PF herda os metodos de Cliente, a classe PF esta assim, Classe PF: `package br.com.diego.controle;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class PF extends Cliente {
    
    public PF(){
        super.setTipo(PF);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remova o atributo `tipo` na sua classe `Cliente`. A anotação `@DiscriminatorColumn` é suficiente.

Se precisar especificar um campo numérico, adicione o atributo `discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER` na anotação `@DiscriminatorColumn`.

Nota: verifique também no seu código que em alguns lugares você está abrindo transações sem dar `commit` ou `rollback`. Precisa mesmo de transação para ler os dados?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @utluiz mas como possou duas classes (PF e PJ) que herdam os métodos e atributos da classe Cliente,  o atributo tipo, pode possuir valor 1 ou 2 para identificar que dentre as classes filhas de Cliente 1 sera usado para PF e 2 sera usado para PJ. `package br.com.diego.controle;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class PF extends Cliente {
    
    public PF(){
        super.setTipo(PF);
    }
}`

Comment: O atributo tipo esta recebendo o valor 1, não entendo pq mesmo fixado o valor o hibernate ainda tenta passar tipo outra vez de acordo com o erro reportado `Hibernate: insert into Cliente (email, nome, senha, tipo) values (?, ?, ?, '1') dez 16, 2015 8:34:55 PM`  `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelperlogExceptions ERROR: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3)`

Comment: @Diego Acho que você não entendeu, não é para remover a anotação, mas o atributo da classe. Estou desconfiado que o hibernate está tentando incluir duas vezes o campo por causa disso.

Comment: Não consegui verificar essa informação, mas em todos os exemplos que eu vi, a anotação contém o nome da coluna discriminatória, mas **não** tem um atributo na classe com o mesmo nome, até porque você não pode em hipótese alguma modificar esse valor. E o hibernate que vai controlar isso através da instância das classes.

Comment: Acertou em cheio @utluiz muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Estou com um problema na autenticação do sistema, poderia me ajudar em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106695/erro-na-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-sistema-web