# Erro na autenticação de um sistema web

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Estou aprendendo junto a um tutorial a desenvolver um sistema de petshop e estou obtendo o seguinte erro do Hibernate:

> Hibernate: select cliente0_.idCliente as idClient2_2_, cliente0_.email as email3_2_, cliente0_.nome as nome4_2_, cliente0_.senha as senha5_2_, cliente0_.tipo as tipo1_2_ from Cliente cliente0_ left outer join PF cliente0_1_ on cliente0_.idCliente=cliente0_1_.idCliente left outer join PJ cliente0_2_ on cliente0_.idCliente=cliente0_2_.idCliente where cliente0_.email=? and cliente0_.senha=?
>   Erro na autenticação

Metodo autenticar(da classe ClienteMTD):

```
public static Autenticavel autenticar(String usuario, String senha) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Cliente p = null;
    try {
        Query q;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        q = session.createQuery("FROM Cliente as p where p.email=:usuario and p.senha=:senha");
        q.setParameter("usuario", usuario);
        q.setParameter("senha", senha);
        List resultados = q.list();
        if (resultados.size() > 0) {
            p = (Cliente) resultados.get(0);
        }
        return p;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return p;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Autenticavel.java:

```
package br.com.diego.controle;

public interface Autenticavel {

public Autenticavel autenticar(String usuario, String senha);

public boolean existe(String usuario);
}
```

TestandoHibernate.java:

```
public class TestandoHibernate {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GerarTabelas();
    if (autenticar("diegopvj@gmail.com", "root") != null) {
        System.out.println("Usuário autenticado");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Erro na autenticação");
    }
    try {
        persistindo();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

 public static Autenticavel autenticar(String usuario, String senha) {
    return new PF().autenticar(usuario, senha);
}

private static void persistindo() throws Exception {
    PF pf = new PF();
    pf.setNome("Diego Juarez");
    pf.setEmail("diegopvj@gmail.com");
    pf.setSenha("root");
    DocReceita CPF = new CPF(" 122. 379. 567-58 ");
    pf.setDocReceita(CPF);
    CPF.setCliente(pf);

    if (pf.existe(CPF) == true) {
        throw new RuntimeException("<br><center><font face='verdana' color='red'   size='2'><br />já existe usuário cadastrado com o CPF ou CNPJ informado</font></center><br>");
    }

    Endereco end = new Endereco();
    end.setBairro("Centro");
    end.setCep("28610175");
    end.setCidade("Nova Friburgo");
    end.setLograd("Pca Presidente Getulio Vargas 220");
    end.setNumero("402");
    end.setUf("RJ");
    end.setCliente(pf);

    Collection<Endereco> e = new ArrayList<Endereco>();
    e.add(end);
    pf.setEndereco(e);

    Telefone t = new Telefone();
    t.setCodArea(21);
    t.setNumero("988336760");
    t.setCliente(pf);

    Collection<Telefone> tel = new ArrayList<Telefone>();
    tel.add(t);
    pf.setTelefone(tel);

    Pet a = new Cachorro();
    Date d = new Date(2010, 04, 26);
    a.setDataNascimento(d);
    a.setNome("Rex");
    a.setRaca("Bulldog");
    a.setSexo('M');
    a.setObs("Peida muito!");
    a.setCliente(pf);

    Servico s = new Consulta();
    s.setData(new Date());
    s.setDescricao("Problema de peso");
    s.setValor(20);
    s.setPet(a);

    Collection<Servico> serv = new ArrayList<Servico>();
    serv.add(s);
    a.setServico(serv);

    Collection<Pet> peti = new ArrayList<Pet>();
    peti.add(a);
    pf.setPet(peti);

    PF.salvar(pf);
}    
}
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar a encontrar o erro? Obrigado desde já!

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
 <!-- Database connection settings -->

    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/petshop1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">6452software</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>


    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.Cliente"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.PF"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.PJ"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.DocReceita"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.CPF"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.CNPJ"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.Endereco"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.Pet"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.Cachorro"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.Gato"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.Servico"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.Banho"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.Consulta"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.Telefone"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.Tosa"/>
<mapping class="br.com.diego.controle.Vacina"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[image: HeidiSQL]

Comment: Você experimentou rodar a query diretamente no MySQL pra ver se ela realmente acha o registro? Eu rodaria isso no mysql: `select cliente0_.idCliente as idClient2_2_, cliente0_.email as email3_2_, cliente0_.nome as nome4_2_, cliente0_.senha as senha5_2_, cliente0_.tipo as tipo1_2_ from Cliente cliente0_ left outer join PF cliente0_1_ on cliente0_.idCliente=cliente0_1_.idCliente left outer join PJ cliente0_2_ on cliente0_.idCliente=cliente0_2_.idCliente where cliente0_.email='diegopvj@gmail.com' and cliente0_.senha='root'`

Comment: Poste o seu persistence.xml, tenho uma leve suspeita que sei onde o erro tá ocorrendo.

Comment: nao possuo persistence.xml somente hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 2):

Não tem erro nenhum.

A mensagem do Hibernate é porque ele está mostrando a query sendo executada, já que você configurou assim através do `show_sql`.

Já o "Erro na autenticação" é sua própria mensagem e significa que a consulta do banco de dados não retornou nenhum registro.

Primeiro, verifique se não tem nenhuma outra mensagem relevante no log.

Segundo, verifique se você realmente tem o registro com os valores correspondentes ao e-mail e senha no banco de dados.

Terceiro, verifique se o Java está executando a última versão do seu código. Compile novamente as classes, remova arquivos temporários, etc.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, era isso mesmo q eu esperava não vejo erros também e de acordo com a foto que coloquei do programa HeidiSQL os valores estão sendo registrados no banco de dados MySQL, continuo sem resolver o problema amigo.

Comment: Poderia ter mais alguma sugestão?

Comment: @diego Uma outra ideia é que seu método de persistir está sendo chamado depois da autenticação, então naquele momento não vai ter nada no banco de dados.

Comment: Fui aconselhado a trocar o bloco do try para antes do bloco de gerar tabelas e consequentemente o método persistir agora esta sendo chamado antes da autenticação mesmo assim continuo com o mesmo problema.

Comment: @diego não é antes do bloco de gerar tabelas. Você precisa manter uma ordem coerente. Primeiro gera tabelas, depois insere os dados e depois acessa os mesmos. De qualquer forma, isso não deveria ser um problema a não ser que você esteja limpando o banco a cada execução do programa. Outros problemas com seu código é que você não usa transação para inserir no banco, mas usa transação para ler os dados. Além disso, fica difícil dizer o que pode estar acontecendo sem ter o log completo. Você chegou a rodar a query do hibernate para ver se ela funciona? Pode ser também problema de permissão.

Answer (score 1):

`public Autenticavel autenticar(String usuario, String senha)` está retornando uma interface, tenta mudar para `public Cliente autenticar(String usuario, String senha)`

Comment: Mudei Autenticavel.java para: `package br.com.diego.controle;

public interface Autenticavel {

    public Cliente autenticar(String usuario, String senha);

    public boolean existe(String usuario);
}` em Cliente.java mudei `@Override
    public Cliente autenticar(String usuario, String senha){
        return (Cliente) ClienteMTD.autenticar(usuario, senha);
        }` e em ClienteMTD.java mudei: `public static Cliente autenticar(String usuario, String senha)` o erro ainda continua o mesmo

Comment: Não entendo pq isto acontece `where cliente0_.email=? and cliente0_.senha=?` será um problema na maneira q escrevi isto `GerarTabelas();
    if (autenticar("diegopvj@gmail.com", "root") != null) {
        System.out.println("Usuário autenticado");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Erro na autenticação");
    }` em TestandoHibernate.java?

Comment: Coloca o bloco do try antes do gerar tabelas e vê se resolveu, não postou o método persistindo inteiro aqui né? tem o método save ou merge nele para persistir?

Comment: Postei o método persistindo inteiro agora, dá uma olhada. tentei colocar o bloco do try antes e ainda continuo com Erro na autenticação.

Comment: Método salvar na Classe ClienteMTD.java: `public class ClienteMTD {
 
    public static boolean salvar(Cliente p) {
        Session session;
        session = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(p);
            tx.commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }`

Comment: Ok, então continua com o block try antes do GerarTabelas e tenta trocar q.list() para q.getResultList()

Comment: No método autenticar? Tentei mudar para q.getResultList() e obtive a mensagem de erro: `cannot find symbol   symbol: method getResultList()   location: variable of type Query`, não sei se entendi direito.